# how to send sending Arabic message in url parameter

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-mvc, httprequest, spring-rest

i am sending an ARABIC message as a parameter in the url fom angularjs as

```
 ` $http({    

                    method : "POST",
                    url : "./SendSMSBulk/"+message+","+lang, 
                    data :$scope.selected
                    }).success(function(data){
                        alert("Sms Sent");
                        $state.reload();

                    });`
```

and the URL is mapped to the Spring REST as

```
@RequestMapping(value="/SendSMSBulk/{message},{lang}")
public ApiResponse sendSmsBulk(@RequestBody List<CustomerData> data,@PathVariable("message") String message,@PathVariable("lang") String lang ) throws IOException{
}
```

when i am passing an english message the API is working fine but when i am passing an Arabic message i am getting 404 error `http://localhost:8080/AIS/SendSMSBulk/%D8%B9%D9%85%D9%8A%D9%84%D9%86%D8%A7%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B9%D8%B2%D9%8A%D8%B2%20%D9%8A%D8%B1%D8%AC%D9%89%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AA%D9%83%D8%B1%D9%85%20%D8%A8%D9%85%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%AC%D8%B9%D8%A9%20%D9%82%D8%B3%D9%85%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B9%D9%82%D9%88%D8%AF%20%D9%88%D8%B0%D9%84%D9%83%20%D9%84%D8%AA%D9%88%D9%82%D9%8A%D8%B9%20%D9%88%20%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AA%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85%20%D8%B9%D9%82%D8%AF%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AA%D9%88%D8%B1%D9%8A%D8%AF%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AE%D8%A7%D8%B5%20%D8%A8%D9%83%D9%85%20.%20%D8%A3%D9%88%D9%82%D8%A7%D8%AA%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B9%D9%85%D9%84%20%D9%85%D9%86%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B3%D8%A8%D8%AA%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%8A%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AE%D9%85%D9%8A%D8%B3%20%D9%85%D9%86%208%20%D8%B5%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%AD%D8%A7%20%D8%AD%D8%AA%D9%89%209%20%D9%85%D8%B3%D8%A7%D8%A1%D8%A7%20%D9%85%D8%B1%D9%83%D8%B2%20%D8%AE%D8%AF%D9%85%D8%A9%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B9%D9%85%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%A1%201800999%20%D8%B4%D8%B1%D9%83%D8%A9%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B5%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%81%20%D9%84%D9%84%D8%A3%D8%A8%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%A8%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AE%D8%B4%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%A9,arabic
Request Method:POST
Status Code:404 Not Found`

how can i send the ARABIC in the url parameter ???

Comment: Please verify $scope.selected matches the fields of Class CustomerData fields

Comment: @J-Mean  
verified it matches all the fields , when i am sending the message in ENGLISH its working perfectly fine but when i send the messsage in ARABIC its getting 404.

Comment: It makes absolutely no sense to pass the message via the URL. It's also semantically wrong. You post data anyway, so add the message to the body. As for the error: The message contains a dot, so it doesn't match the request mapping.

Comment: @zeroflagL it makes sense for me because the data i am sending is customer information and its a list of customers i cannot add a message to customer object and add it for every customer that will be a wrong approach i feel

Comment: _"i cannot add a message to customer object"_ Why should you?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not a solution , but I would try to modify your solution.

1. Remove the message from the url, you are posting, send message as parameter instead. Like { messageText: message, lang: lang }
2. Change @RequestMapping(value="/SendSMSBulk")
3. Read data from parameterd in Spring

public ApiResponse sendSmsBulk(@RequestBody List data,@RequestParam("message") String message,@RequestParam("lang") String lang )

Then see if you have encoding errors. Sending non ascii characters as url parameters can get you in all sorts or problems, at least that's my experience.